# Regex to match number of chars in groups separated by dashes?

Tags: regex

Here is the string I want to match `76c24efd-ec42-492a-92df-c62cfd4540a3`. The following regex will match a 36 char length string with alphanumeric characters and '-'.

`[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{36}`

I am trying to add to this regex, so it matches only when `<8 chars> - <4 chars> - <4 chars> - <4 chars> - <12 chars>`

Comment: Use: `^[a-f0-9]{8}-(?:[a-f0-9]{4}-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}$`

Comment: @anubhava this expression will match hexadecimal characters, which looks like what the op wanted, however if they wish to match alphanumeric characters they should replace all instances of "f" with "z"

Answer (score 0):

The following will match a group of 8 characters followed by a dash, then a group of 4 characters followed by a dash 3 times, and then a group of 12 characters.

```
^[a-z0-9]{8}-(?:[a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{12}$/
```

Here's a short JavaScript test that shows the results.

```js
$('.test').each(function(row, item) {
   var val = $($(item).children()[0]).html()
   var result = /^[a-z0-9]{8}-(?:[a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{12}$/gi.test(val);
   $($(item).children()[1]).html(result.toString())
});
```

```css
th {
   text-align:left;
   padding-right:10px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
   <tr><th>Test</th><th>Result</th><th>Desired Result</th></tr>
   <tr class="test"><td>76c24efd-ec42-492a-92df-c62cfd4540a3</td><td></td><td>Good</td></tr>
   <tr class="test"><td>76c24efd-ecz42-492a-92df-c62cfd4540a3</td><td></td><td>Bad Length - 2nd segment too long</td></tr>
   <tr class="test"><td>76c24efd-ec2-492a-92df-c62cfd4540a31</td><td></td><td>Bad Segment Lengths</td></tr>
   <tr class="test"><td>76$24efd-ec42-492a-92df-c62cfd4540a3</td><td></td><td>Bad Char ($)</td></tr>
</table>
```